# authenticate a website and get the response header

Tags: python, request

I tried this one

```
s = requests.Session()

s.auth = ('user', 'pass')

s.headers.update({'x-test': 'true'})

s.get('http://httpbin.org/headers', headers={'x-test2': 'true'})
```

But i get html output not look like what I required.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `import` statement:

```
>>> s = requests.Session()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined

>>> import requests # <----------------------------
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>>
```

BTW, Make sure you installed [`python-requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Comment: That was not the real matter, i want to login a website and get the response not the html file i stored in templates. can i do it with this?